# Totalize component products from table

Tags: r, aggregate

I need my warehouse to be able to know how many items of each component we need per day. Basically, I have bundled items made of single products, and I want the warehouse to know how many of those single items they should provide in any given date.

I currently have data like this:

```
   date      bundle_name  totbund   prod1  totprod1  prod2  totprod2  
06/01/2019      a_bund       1        a       1        b       1
06/01/2019        a          1
06/01/2019        b          2
07/01/2019      b_bund       1        b       2
07/01/2019      b_bund       2        b       4
07/01/2019        b          2
```

My expected output is this:

```
    date    all_item   total
06/01/2019     a         2
06/01/2019     b         3
07/01/2019     b         8
```

Please notice that the `bundle_item` column can have bundled items or a single item, so it is mixed.

Comment: The math behind your aggregation is not clear to me. On `06/01`, I think `a,1` and `b,2` translate into the next two *rows* of the frame; but this logic does not carry forward for `07/01`. Nor do I understand how *"multiplication"* comes into play.

Comment: I'm sorry. I got wrong tag. It should be addition to single item, so i could get the accumulation number of it

Comment: It seems to me that your approach is very cumbersome. I suggest you read about structured databases, as what you want is nothing else but a join between a table of requirements and a table of components. Once you have both tables in the correct format, there are plenty of threads here in SO about how to make a join

Comment: @PavoDive yes, it's really complicated. I already state how to differentiate between bundled items and single items below in the comment. Could it be possible to done this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work (I use 'a' as an example):

```
      dat = dat %>%
        group_by(date) %>%
        summarize(a_bund = sum(tot_bund[bundle_name=='a']),
                  a_prod1 = sum(prod1[totprod1=='a']),
                  a_prod2 = sum(prod2[totprod2=='a'])) %>%
        mutate(a = a_bund+a_prod1+a_prod2)
```

Comment: I mean it is likely have many bundled items and each bundled type could have many combinations of single item

Comment: If b_bund can signify different bundle types and amounts, I'm afraid there's no way to automate it.

Comment: Actually the real bundle name can be differentiated like this. The single item's bundle name will be purely number code like 123456, but bundled item's looks like 123456P3, 12P23P. So, bundled item code usually has an alphabet or several alphabets.

Comment: Could it be possible to do this?

Comment: You'd probably have to create a dictionary converting the codes to product types and numbers. Then you could properly automate the system.

Comment: I have the dictionary for the bundled item, so it can be separated to its single items on the right columns like in the example. It's actually really complicated to sum up the single item in bundled_name column with the separated bundled items.

Comment: If I understand right, then I think my answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the bundled notation, it sounds overly complicated. If you have everything in a row-format, you can use the group_by - summarize functionality of dplyr.

Assuming the data is called 'df'

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  select(date, prod = prod1, totprod = totprod1) %>%
  filter(prod != "") %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% select(date, prod = prod2, totprod = totprod2) %>% filter(prod != "") %>%
  group_by(date, prod) %>%
  summarize(totprod = sum(totprod))
```

Comment: What actually the "prod!" means?

Comment: `prod` is for `prod`uct, a way to multiply all components in a vector. Try `prod(1,2,4)`.

Comment: I renamed prod1 and prod2 to just prod. So it stands for product. `filter(prod != "")` removes empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

I commented you needed a better approach at this problem.

I suggest you consider this from a *structured database* perspective. In such view, your data (and thus your world) is made of tables with differing and complementary information. And when you need to obtain information to solve your problem, you **join** data from different tables. If you have used excel, then you'll know it as `vlookup`.

How I'd approach your problem:

#### Table of components:

First, I'll have a table of components. This would be a very simple table of 3 columns: `name` of the product, `component` from which it is made and `amount` of component needed.

For your example, I'll have

```
library(data.table)

components <- structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "a_bund", "a_bund", "b_bund"), 
                             component = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "b"),
                             amount = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2)), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
                        class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Which will produce:

```
components
     name component amount
1:      a         a      1
2:      b         b      1
3: a_bund         a      1
4: a_bund         b      1
5: b_bund         b      2
```

Notice that the information contained here is just the same information that you have in your table in columns 4 to 7 (by the way, your table is called "wide", while mine is "long" formatted. Long is much better for machine processing, and it's considered "tidy").

#### Table of Requests

Now that you have a table for the components, you'll need a table to put how many units of product *x* your clients need by *y* date. Do you notice that I separated the information content in both tables? There's one with components and nothing else; and there's one with requests and nothing else. Each thingy in its own basket!

This table I called `requests` and it's composed of three columns: `dates` with the date of the request, `name` with the name of the product requested by the client, and `qty` with the quantity the client expects of the product. That would be what you have in columns one to three in your data.

```
requests <- structure(list(dates = structure(c(17902, 17902, 17902, 17903, 17903, 17903), class = "Date"), 
                           name = c("a_bund", "a", "b", "b_bund", "b_bund", "b"), 
                           qty = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
                      class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Which produces:

```
requests
        dates   name qty
1: 2019-01-06 a_bund   1
2: 2019-01-06      a   1
3: 2019-01-06      b   2
4: 2019-01-07 b_bund   1
5: 2019-01-07 b_bund   2
6: 2019-01-07      b   2
```

#### Joining the tables

With these two tables, you now need to know how many of each component you'll need in any given date. To solve this I'll use the data.table package, please see `?data.table` for details.

```
requests[components, on = "name" ][, sum(qty*amount), by = .(dates, component)]
```

What is in there?

`requests[components, on = "name"]` joins the table `requests` with `components` by matching elements with the same `name`. In other words, it brings the `component` and `amount` (from components, of course) for each `name` in `requests`. Paste the command and see what the result is.

Data.table syntaxis allows "chaining" or passing an intermediate result to a new operation. That's what happens with the `][` sequence: I joined the tables and now am feeding that result into a new operation.

That new operation is `sum(qty * amount)`. It is multiplying (you weren't wrong initially) the number of requested units `qty` by the amount of each `component` needed to produce it, and sums it (aggregates it) `by = .(dates, component)`, which seems pretty self-explanatory. (If you come from the excel world, just think about a pivot or dynamic table).

That produces your expected output:

```
requests[components, on = "name" ][, sum(qty*amount), by = .(dates, component)]
        dates component V1
1: 2019-01-06         a  2
2: 2019-01-06         b  3
3: 2019-01-07         b  8
```

While the result is the same other answers already provided, I hope you see the difference in approaches, and the enhanced usability of this one. If not, just imagine that `k_bundle` is made of **19 different components** ;)

Comment: several items have several components in itself. I mean like item1 could have 2 components in it. I have made the dictionary for the components detail, so the column will be looked like "name, component1, amount1, component2, amount2, component3, amount3 ... , component5, amount5

so could your code do this?

Comment: I thought it was clear I understood that. Now think that at any point you could have a boundled item made of many (a lot more than two) components: You'll need a better approach or you'll collapse!